# SQL: SELECT distinct paired values based on most number of occurences

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
SELECT Distinct Contract, Description
FROM Statement
```

Usually each contract has one description, and vice-versa.
It happens however that contract may have a typo. This results in two rows for what should be the same pair instance.

This becomes problematic, and I'm looking for a workaround.
In case of mismatch I hope to compare the frequencies of the possible Contract for each description, and select only the most frequent one.

For example:

```
Contract        Description
  X                XX
  X                XX
  Y                YY
  A                XX
```

The query would return three pairs:

```
  X : XX
  Y : YY
  A : XX
```

I hope to fix it, so that it returns only the following pairs:

```
  X : XX
  Y : YY
```

Any suggestion is most welcome.
I am using SQL Server.

Comment: Why is ` A : XX` not a distinct pair

Comment: you may need to `group by`

Comment: What if you have `A's=X's` which description would you take?

Comment: @Matt  'A : XX'  is a distinct pair, and i hope to exclude it because A is a mistake, by restricting one contract to each description, and selecting the most frequent contract.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select description, contract
from (select description, contract, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by description order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by description, contract
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

What you are looking for has a name in statistics.  It is called the `mode`.  This is the most common value in a set of data (or a particular group).

Note:  The above will return a unique mode for each `description`.  There can be ties.  If you need all values, then use `rank()` or `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

Test it on rextester: http://rextester.com/MODKIE76399

Comment: do u know a way to also apply in ms access??

Comment: @Kelaref . . . Your question is tagged SQL Server.  If you have a question about MS Access, you should ask another question.  The solution would be quite different, because SQL Server offers more functionality in this area.